# Increase row value in a formula by dragging to the right

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one worksheet that has a table of data that is 15 columns by 20 rows. Each cell is linked to a specific cell on another tab. How do I drag the cell to the right to increase the row number? For example in the string below I want to drag the cell to the right and increase K40 to K41, 42, 43, 44 etc. but leave the rest:

```
='18 - UB ASSY MEGA CAB'!K40
```

Answer (score 5):

In *Sheet1* cell **A1** enter:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,39+COLUMNS($A:A),10)
```

and copy across.

This will display *Sheet2* cells **K40, K41, K42, ...**

Comment: Note that `OFFSET` is a volatile function.

Answer (score 5):

Use the non volatile INDEX():

```
=INDEX('18 - UB ASSY MEGA CAB'!$K:$K,COLUMN(A:A)+39)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily [Transpose your table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419F2E3-BEAB-4318-AAE5-D0F862209744) to autofill it, then transpose again if you want to keep the original layout. (you'll need to paste it to an empty space while you do this. The source and destination can't overlap.

In addition to that, you can choose which parts of your formula can be adjusted when autofilling, and which must remain constant, by using 'absolute references'. Prefix a column, row, or both by using a $. For example, a reference $A1 can autofill vertically but not horizontally, A$2 is the opposite. $A$1 is absolute in both directions and will never move.